# MySQL, modifying primary-key column

Tags: mysql, sorting, warnings, primary-key

---

```
number(pk)   name
    1         A 
    2         B  
    4         C
    5         D 
    8         E
   10         F
   12         G
   15         H
   20         I
```

---

I want to modify above table like below.

---

```
number(pk)  name
    1         A
    2         B
    3         C
    4         D
    5         E
    6         F
    7         G
    8         H
    9         I
```

---

For this, I found the following code on the Internet

```
SET @CNT = 0;
UPDATE [table_name] SET [column_name] = @CNT:=@CNT+1;
```

This worked as I wanted, but the following warning appears.

> warning(s): 1287 Setting user variables within expressions is
> deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider
> alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s)
> INTO variables(s)'.

could you tell me other better ways or the way avoiding the warnig?

Comment: DONT!!! Simple dont even consider it, ___there be dragons___ There is no good reason for doing this anyway

Comment: Primary key must be unchanged. If you need a column with consecutive values then add one more column into the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Not advised, but if you really want to do this you can export the table, delete it and import it without the primary key column which will get auto auto incremented